# Replacing %26 by & in query string with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

Have tried countless RewriteRule, including those suggested by previous posts.
Unefortunately, none works with my problem.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Post your non-working example?

Comment: Is this a problem with the URL rewriting, or are you trying to fix an URL that comes in broken to start with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^%]+|%([013-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]|2[0-57-9a-fA-F]))*)%26(.*)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1&%4 [N]
```

Comment: Fantastic !!! When I got my approval, I just could not believe my eyes !!! I wanted to vote up but I am not allowed yet :-( Anyway thanks a lot. Have a great day. Francois

Answer (score 0):

1. First, add to you vhost config: (adding to .htaccess won't work)

   ```
   RewriteMap escape int:escape
   ```
2. Next, replace any occurrence of a variable in question with `${escape:$N}`, e.g. replace

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ ?query=$1 [L,QSA]
   ```

   with

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ ?query=${escape:$1} [L,QSA]
   ```

Comment: Thanks but this solution does not work for me. However I surely have applied your recommendation incorrectly.
The problem is that some mail server translates my URL sent out in a mail with : https://www.mysite.com/verif.php?param1=1%26param2=2 (with %26 instead of &). I would like to change it back.
My virtual host config is :
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap escape int:escape
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ ?query=${escape:$1} [L,QSA]
Thanks !